# SQL Server: retrieve data to variable in query to in-query usage

Tags: sql-server

I have a T-SQL big query:

```
SELECT ( ... some big subquery ... ), 
  ( ... some big subquery ... ) / field1, 
  CASE WHEN ( ... some big subquery ... ) = 0 THEN ... ELSE ... END
FROM table
WHERE ( ... some big subquery ... ) IS NOT NULL
```

Is there a way to make it in mysql way:

```
SELECT @big_query_result := ( ... some big subquery ... ), 
  @big_query_result / field1, 
  CASE WHEN @big_query_result = 0 THEN ... ELSE ... END
FROM table
WHERE @big_query_result IS NOT NULL
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Use a Common Table expression for this:

```
;WITH CTE_Results AS
(
SELECT ID, (SOME BIG SUB QUERY) AS SubResult FROM table
)
SELECT 
RES.SubResult
, RES.SubResult/TBL.field1
, CASE WHEN RES.SubResult = 0 THEN... ELSE ... END AS FieldName
FROM table TBL
INNER JOIN CTE_Results RES
ON TBL.ID = RES.ID
WHERE RES.SubResult IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Note that using an alias will not work for you as you need to use it in your Where clause and an Alias cannot be used in your where clause.

Comment: To clarify, Charl means that using an alias in the WHERE clause of your MySQL example would not work.  SQL Server allows aliases in the WHERE clause, and thus the "WHERE RES.SubResult" alias in his answer is valid.

Comment: Jonathan, that's not what I mean ;-> This is for MSSQL. Table aliases are valid in WHERE clauses, but not Column aliases for columns that are calculated in your select statement. Using the CTE means we don't have to use and alias of a calculated column in the select clause, but we still use the table alias RES. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I understood that your answer was targeting MSSQL. So what you meant was that e.g. adding "AND FieldName = 'Sales'" to the WHERE clause would not be valid because the column alias is being created as part of the SELECT? If so, that was not clear in your initial comment and should probably be amended to clearly say "column alias" instead of just "alias". And "you need to use it" changed to "you *would* need to use it" since your answer actually does what OP *needs* to do and you are really just tacking on a warning for modifying the query further.

Comment: Please read the whole post again. The issue here is that the user has a SQL query that he wants to do in a MySQL way. In Summary: You cannot use column aliases for calculated columns in your WHERE clause. Table aliases are valid to use. In our example, we do not use any column aliases. We do use table aliases... If it's still peculiarly dizzy - just use the query and see what happens. ;->

Comment: I fully understood that the user was trying to do a SQL query in a MySQL way. You actually conceded that your original comment was confusing, then deleted that concession and added this instead. Well, whatever....my whole mission here was to make sure OP was not confused and I think we have reached the point where further discussion will not be helpful to him/her. Leaving my vote in place because your answer was sound, but I regard this entire sequence of comments from start to finish as fundamentally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to give the "big query" an alias, like:

```
select  BigQueryResult
,       BigQueryResult / field1
,       case when BigQueryResult = 0 then ... else ... end
from    (
        select   ( ... some big subquery ... ) as BigQueryResult
        ,        ... other columns ...
        from     table
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```